Boot hangs after verify DMI pool
I have an older Gigabyte/AMD (6+ years) PC set up to dual boot Windows 10 or Ubuntu 24.04 off of a 240 GB SSD. I also have a 2 TB hard drive for data storage. The windows partition is full, so I decided to repartition and use some of the unused space from the Linux partition on the Windows one. But first I tried to backup the SSD to another 240GB SSD using Disk Destroyer. I thought I would be safe since I wouldn't be touching the original SSD. I ran sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4MB status=progress where sdb was the original and sdc the new SSD from a live Lubuntu session. It completed successfully and fsck showed no errors on the original and one on the copy, but when I tried to boot to the original SSD with the copy removed, the computer hangs after DMI pool verification. I suspect a problem with GRUB but since the original was only read I don't understand why using dd should cause the boot to fail.  I tried boot-repair tool which indicated success but no joy on booting. I've searched but not found anyone in the same boat. Any help and suggestions appreciated.
After posting this, I disconnected the hard drive from the MB and the computer booted as usual from the original SSD.  I went into the bios and the boot options are the usual suspects--CDROM, HDD and a variety of USB options, but I don't see anything for SSD or SATA.  Am I looking in the wrong place?  How do I set the bios to boot from the SSD when hard disk is the only option in the bios?  And again why this problem after doing a dd clone?

Sometimes it is the obvious.  Apparently the SATA connector wasn't seated properly.  All is working as before.  Now to verify the clone and get those partitions resized!  Also time to build a new desktop.  I didn't realize how old this one is!
